# PHPMailer doesn't work, page gets white

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email with PHPMailer, but everytime I press to send, the page turns white. I tried to search in the error_log but nothing appeared inside. By the way, I'm using ajax, all the plugins are included and working.

This is the code I have:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cod_ajax/enviar_email.php",
            data: "nome="+nome+"&last="+last+"&email="+email+"&assunto="+assunto+"&texto="+texto,
            success:function(e){
                document.write(e);
                $("#envia_email").prop("disabled", true);
              setInterval(function(){
                $("#envia_email").html("Email Enviado com sucesso! Recarregue a página para enviar outro!");
              }, 2000);
                $(".erros").fadeOut(0);
                $("#name").val("");
                $("#last").val("");
                $("#email").val("");
                $("#assunto").val("");
                $("#texto").val("");
            }
        })
```

All variables are right, nothing is empty and receive well the information. This is my ajax file:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$last=$_POST['last'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$assunto=$_POST['assunto'];
$texto=$_POST['texto'];

require '../mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('b_daniel_18@hotmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('b_sem_l@hotmail.com');
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
}
```

I didn't use the variables because it didn't work so I tried adding information manually, still didn't work.

***UPDATE***

Removed the `if(isset($_POST['name']))` and I can see the errors now. It doesn't send, appears ***Mailer error: Could not instantiate mail function.***

Comment: to see the error, set up the error callback on the ajax call and console.log the response

Comment: Do you see _Message was not sent._ or _Message has been sent._ ?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Also, on your send button, did you use preventDefault()?

Comment: Enable PHP errors: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Difster No erros on console

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs How?

Comment: @codtex Nothing happened, just white page

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho see my answer

Comment: can you send mails using `if(mail('yourmail@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body')) { echo 'ok';}  else { echo 'not ok'; }`

Comment: @IvoP Got not ok

Comment: so the mail function is not working at all. Therefor PHPMailer cannot function either. Or you should use a smpt server elsewhere

Comment: Test without involving ajax - test your PHP directly. It's easy for error messages to be lost when using ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped your form variable name in the php file.  Change

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
```

To:

```
if(isset($_POST['nome']))
```

Comment: that won't result in WOAD though, just a warning

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Username = "b_daniel_18@hotmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "mypassword";
        $mail->AddAddress("b_sem_l@hotmail.com");
        $mail->FromName = "My Name";
        $mail->Subject = "My Subject";
        $mail->Body = "My Body";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->From = $mail->Username;
        if($mail->Send()){
        echo 'Sent.<br/>';
        }else{
         echo 'Not sent: <pre>'.print_r(error_get_last(), true).'</pre>';
        }
```

Comment: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory This is what appeared

Comment: It says: ***phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons***